# How to draw a simple hierarchical relationships in LaTex (additional question)

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

This is a follow up a question from [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585255/how-to-draw-a-simple-hierarchical-relationships-in-latex/585256#585256)

[image]

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw,
    semithick,
    rounded corners,
    text width=6em,
    text badly centered,
    minimum height=4ex,
    edge={
            draw=blue},
    anchor= north,
    grow=south,
    forked edge,
    s sep=4mm,
    l sep=12mm,
    fork sep=6mm,
}
[sample number 1[pure fruit][non pure fruit[water abc][sugar \\contaminated]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

How can i add in this new part:

[image]

Comment: please have a look at the answer below

Comment: @jsbibra thank you very much. Brillant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw,
    semithick,
    rounded corners,
    text width=6em,
    text badly centered,
    minimum height=6ex,
    edge={draw=blue},
    anchor= north,
    grow=south,
    forked edge,
    s sep=4mm,
    l sep=5mm,
    fork sep=3mm,
    inner sep=1pt
}
[sample number 1[pure fruit[water abc][sugar \\contaminated]][non pure fruit[water abc][sugar \\contaminated]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```